# Raising minimum OpenID version requirement for Providers to 2.0 to protect this stateless RP from replay attacks

Tags: c#, .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

We use `OpenAuthAuthentiocation.dll` and get the following warning:

> Raising minimum OpenID version requirement for Providers to 2.0 to
>   protect this stateless RP from replay attacks

How can we fix it? How can I make this warning disappear?

Comment: This is not a question.  And the message you quote is not an error.  It's an informational warning.

Comment: @AndrewArnott My question was modified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the warning disappear by raising the minimum OpenID version requirement for Providers to 2.0 yourself in your [configuration file](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/?page_id=1116)<sup>[semi-dead link]</sup>.

```
<dotNetOpenAuth>
    <openid>
        <relyingParty>
            <security minimumRequiredOpenIdVersion="V20" />
        </relyingParty>
    </openid>
</dotNetOpenAuth>
```

The effect is the same on your RP, but since you're doing it yourself, DotNetOpenAuth won't warn you that it is doing it for you.